# PHP variable scope confused

Tags: php, variables, scope

Hello
Here is my code.... THe problem is at `$product`  variable.
Is there any way to fix this?
It is defined two times and causes problem overwrites

## THE PROBLEM UPDATED

```
   $productsIDs = array();
        foreach ($rowsProducts as &$product) {
            $product["features"] = &$productsFeatures[$product["product_id"]];
            $productsIDs[] = $product["product_id"];
        }

//GET STOCK FEATURES
$sqlIds=implode(",",$productsIDs);
$sql="SELECT * FROM eshop_products_stock WHERE product_id IN ($sqlIds)";

$productsStock = $db->getRecordSet($sql);
$sql="SELECT * FROM `eshop_features_valuestr` WHERE feature_id IN ".
      "(SELECT DISTINCT feature1_id FROM eshop_products_stock WHERE product_id IN ($sqlIds))" .
        " AND language_code='$lang'";

$productsSizes = $db->getRecordSet($sql);
 $sql="SELECT * FROM `eshop_features_valuestr` WHERE feature_id IN ".
      "(SELECT DISTINCT feature2_id FROM eshop_products_stock WHERE product_id IN ($sqlIds))".
        " AND language_code='$lang'";;
$productsColors = $db->getRecordSet($sql);

$productsSizesV=array();
foreach($productsSizes as $size)
{
    $productsSizesV[$size["value"]]=$size["title"];
}

$productsColorsV=array();
foreach($productsColors as $color)
{
    $productsColorsV[$color["value"]]=$color["title"];
}
//Group by product stock
$productsStockV=array();
$product="";

foreach($productsStock as $product)
{
   $productsStockV[$product["product_id"]]["sizes"][]=$product["feature1_value"];
   $productsStockV[$product["product_id"]]["colors"][]=$product["feature2_value"];
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: There's no need to "declare" `$product` before the `foreach` loop; you should remove the line `$product=""` as it only confuses things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've encountered a very nice php WTF:
`foreach ($rowsProducts as &$product)` makes $product a reference. Not only for the loop but **forever**. If you then use a foreach using $product as the loop variable later (or do anything writing to $product), it will overwrite the last item of the first foreach loop.

Simply use `foreach ($rowsProducts as $key => $product)` and assign `$rowsProducts[$key] = $product;` at the end of your loop body if you changed anything.

Another solution would be calling `unset($product);` after your first loop to get rid of the reference. But generally not using reference loops is safer as you cannot forget to unset.

Answer (score 4):

You should unset `$product` after the `foreach` loop:

```
foreach ($rowsProducts as &$product) {
      $product["features"] = &$productsFeatures[$product["product_id"]];
      $productsIDs[] = $product["product_id"];
}
unset($product);
```